# System.InvalidOperationException occurs with EF6 when connecting to AWS database but not when connecting to on-prem database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-6

When I debug my app using two on-prem databases, I can return data from both of them. But when I change the connection strings to connect to AWS, I can return data from Database 1 but get an error when attempting to return data from Database 2.

I double-checked the connection string syntax, and it looks correct to me.

In BeakersController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return View(db.Beakers.ToList());
    }
```

I get the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type Beaker is not part of the model for the current context.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the database names were defined in a database table. I had to update the names in the AWS database. This was specific to the application and had nothing to do with AWS.